# Two mathematically similar shapes....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, physics, word-problem

I've researched this question but explanations that I have found were either not thorough enough or simply seemed downright incorrect.

I thought it looked quite simple when I first saw it but it stumped me, Hopefully you can help me with this.

*A and B are 2 shapes which are mathematically similar. The shapes are made from the same material.*

*The surface area of A is 50cm squared* 
*The surface area of B is 18cm squared*

*The mass of A is 500 grams*

*Calculate the mass of B*

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well I'm assuming its to do with simple proportions, and that if the mass is 500 grams for A, then the mass for B must be 180 grams. My friend did something completely different though, so that's what has thrown me off.

Comment: What has your friend done?

Comment: Can't remember I'm afraid, I've just pulled this question up from a past paper we did this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass is proportional to **volume** not surface area.  In general surface area is proportional to the **square** of a linear measurement and volume is equal to the cube of a linear measurement.  So volume is proportional to the 3/2 power of surface area.  The ratio of areas is 50/18 so the ratio of volumes is $(50/18)^{3/2}= 4.63.  Since A has mass 500 grams, B has mass 500/4.63= 108 grams.

(Actually, I am not convinced that "mathematically similar" means the objects have the same **density**.)

Comment: Same material implies same density.

Comment: Are these 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional shapes?

Comment: Since the problem asked for mass, we must assume 3 dimensions.

Comment: Doug M: "Same material implies same density."  Ahh, thanks.  I had overlooked that line.